# Ember's input helper need double click to edit in ie11

Tags: ember.js, input, internet-explorer-11, helper

```
<div draggable="true">
  {{input value="default value" }}  
</div>
```

In ember.js, as above code, when the div element has an attribute 'draggable="true"', on the webpage, the input area must need a double-click to edit in ie-11, but in chrome or firefox, it just need a click event to edit. Has anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: you mean before the `focus` event fires?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be a bug

[[IE 11] Input field of type text does not respond to mouse clicks when ancestor node has draggable=true](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/927470/ie-11-input-field-of-type-text-does-not-respond-to-mouse-clicks-when-ancestor-node-has-draggable-true#tabs)

bad workaround:

```
        <div style="background-color:lightgray" id="dragE" draggable="true">
            <input id="inputE" type="text" />
        </div>
```

1. click on the lightgray background
2. now the input field support single click

> ```
> $('#dragE').focus(); <br>
> $('#inputE').focus();<br>
> ```

was my solution

unfotunately reproducing with pluncer & co. did not work.

Comment: only link giving is less appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Or...set attribute draggable to "false", when the page goes to a production environment.

This worked for us.